# Why doesn't wrap function in Python get executed when I call it?

Tags: python

I have this simple code.

```
def decor(func):
  def wrap():
    print("============")
    func()
    print("============")
  return wrap

def print_text():
  print("Hello world!")

decor(print_text())
```

Why does this only print "Hello world!" and not the two wrappers?

Comment: Because you are calling `print_text()` to pass it's return value (which is `None` btw.) as argument to decor (that's when printing happens), after that you call `decor` (which has none of visible side effects) and __throw away__ returned value. Throwing away returned value also has none of visible side effects. Correct way of using decorator is `print_text = decor(print_text)` and after that you may call `print_test()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `decor` with a single argument.  That argument is whatever `print_text()` returns.  Well, `print_text()` prints something and then returns None.  So far, your output is just `Hello world!`.  None is now passed to `decor`, and it returns the `wrap()` function.  Nowhere is `wrap()` actually called, and your final output is just `Hello world!`.

You are misunderstanding the use of decorators. The correct syntax is this:

```
@decor
def print_text():
    print("Hello world!")
```

That is a shortcut for this:

```
def print_text():
    print("Hello world!")

print_text = decor(print_text)
```

Now you can see that it is the returns of `decor(print_text)` (the `wrap()` function) that is being called, and everything is printed.

Comment: Thank you very much. A couple of things unclear though still. When I call decor(), doesn't that automatically call wrap() as well, since it's nested in decor?

Comment: @Fuad: No.  All it does is define the function.  It is the `print_text()` (after `print_text = decor(print_text)` that calls `wrap()`.

Comment: Oh, so when I want to call a nested function, I have to use an additional set of parentheses? So decor(argument)(), where the empty set of parentheses calls the nested function? If I'm correct, what if you have a nested function inside a nested function? Do you do decor(arg)()()? Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated

Comment: @Fuad: Yes. `decor(print_text)` returns a function.  If you want to call that function, you need to add some parentheses.  If the that function returns another function, you will need some more parentheses to call that.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are evaluating `print_text` (thus printing "Hello World!"), and passing the result to `decor`:

```
decor(print_text())
```

Here we are passing `print_text` to `decor`, and calling the resulting function which it returns, which is `wrap`::

```
decor(print_text)()
```

Notice that the first case will NOT call the function returned from `decor`. Try to call it and see what happens:

```
decor(print_text())()
```

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

because `func` is now `None`.

Comment: Thank you Michael. One thing I don't understand - I've defined decor as decor(func), so why doesn't decor get called when I replace 'func' by print_text()? Why do I need two sets of parentheses, like in your decor(print_text())(), one which includes (print_text) and another one empty?

Comment: `decor` **does** get called. The returned function, however, isn't.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you only return the function wrap - It is not called. If you do call it, either by assigning the result to a variable, or by using `decor(print_text)()` directly. Note that you should use `print_text` and not `print_text()`, as the latter will give the result of the function to decor, rather than the function itself. The working version would be:

```
def decor(func):
  def wrap():
    print("============")
    func()
    print("============")
  return wrap

def print_text():
  print "Hello world!"

wrapped_function = decor(print_text)
wrapped_function()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Lolgast. I'm currently learning Python on SoloLearn and they gave the code exactly the same way as you do, and I was wondering how I could print the whole shebang without having it assigned to a variable first. Please have a look at the very simple code below:

`def square(var):
 print(var**2)`
square(2) will now print out 4. In a similar way, I thought decor(print_text()) calls decor first, which goes through wrap(), which in turn calls print_text. Since decor is called, doesn't that mean the nested wrap function is automatically called as well?

Comment: No. In your decor function, you only _define_ wrap (and return it), you don't call it anywhere. It is similar to the way you defined decor: You define it, but until you call decor(some_argument), nothing happens.